# Just trying to store 6 array values into localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

The array oldData [] holds 6 values. (integer values fetched from api).
All I want to do is put these values in 1 localStorage key called 'olddata'.

I've searched everywhere and didn't find anything that make this work.
Could please someone help me with a simple solution?

The way I'm trying now:

```
        let oldData = [];
        oldData.push(parkingData.availableCapacity);
        console.log(oldData); // Definitely holds 6 values 
        localStorage.setItem('olddata', oldData); // Only stores the last value 
        of oldData
```

Also tried a few loops but didn't succeed.

Answer (score 1):

`localStorage` only stores strings.

Use `JSON.stringify()` to set an array as string and `JSON.parse()` to parse that same string back to array when you retrieve the data

```
 localStorage.setItem('olddata', JSON.stringify(oldData));
```

Comment: Yes sorry I forget to mention that but already tried the JSON.stringify,It doesn't work.
Only difference in result is this:

no stringify: 302
JSON.stringify: [302]

Comment: So it just keeps taking the last value and doesn't put the full array in the localStorage key ...

Comment: Something wrong then that isn't shown. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: I'm guessing the array is being populated after you try to store it. What you see in console is a live object not a snapshot. Confirm with `console.log(oldData.join());`

Comment: Just tried console.log(oldData.join()); Result is 6 values

Comment: So how are you determining that only last value exists in the array? My guess is your problem is in code that retrieves it or you have another instance somewhere that overwrites the localStorage

Comment: Can I put my code again somewhere? So you can have a quick look. It's not possible in this comment section

Answer (score 0):

```
let url = 'https://datatank.stad.gent/4/mobiliteit/bezettingparkingsrealtime.json#';
let percent;
let mainDiv = document.getElementById('mainDiv');


function fetchParkingData() {
fetch(url)
.then((resp) => resp.json())
.then(function(data) {

    mainDiv.innerHTML = "";
    for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        let parkingData = {
            name: data[i].name,
            totalCapacity: data[i].parkingStatus.totalCapacity,
            availableCapacity: data[i].parkingStatus.availableCapacity,
        }


        let oldData = [];
        oldData.push(JSON.parse(parkingData.availableCapacity));
        console.log(oldData);
        // console.log(oldData.join());
        localStorage.setItem('dataObject', JSON.stringify(oldData));
    };
})

.catch(function(error) {
    // error handling
    parkingDiv.innerHTML = 'Data could not be fetched';
});
}
```

Comment: Hmm I made a new array now called names, put 6 values in it and then pushed them to the oldData array and that gives me the wanted result, so there is something wrong when I push the parkingData but I don't know what

Comment: What it does is creating like 6 arrays in the oldData array and put al the values under the 0 index

Comment: You need to create the array before the loop and only store it after the loop. You creating a new array and writing to storage every iteration which is why you only see last item

Comment: @charlietfl That fixed the problem. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Browser console commands and output here:

```
>let oldData = [];
undefined
>oldData.push('1st Value');
1
>oldData.push('2nd Value');
2
>oldData.push('3rd Value');
3
>console.log(oldData);
(3) ["1st Value", "2nd Value", "3rd Value"]
undefined
>localStorage.setItem('oldData', JSON.stringify(oldData));
undefined
>JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('oldData'));
(3) ["1st Value", "2nd Value", "3rd Value"]
```